# Java Function exception check

Tags: java

While my counter value is [] (null), means ITSystems value is null;
But in the last if counter value is null, it is still going inside if and printing the exception which I need to be ignored

```
System.out.println(comp.getHardwarekomponente().getItSystems());
Set<ItSystem> counter=comp.getHardwarekomponente().getItSystems();
if (!comp.isVirtualNexusSwitch()) {
    if (comp.isInheritedRedundant() || comp.isRedundant()) {
        if(counter != null){
            throw new ServiceException(ServiceException.LOGIC_REDUNDANT_ITEMS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to say `comp.getHardwarekomponente().getItSystems()` is null? Also which if you want to ignore? From the code snippet you have shared the if conditions does not have link with the `ITSystems`. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!"".equals(comp.getHardwarekomponente().getItSystemsListDisp())`
where ItSystemListDisp() is a seperate function which gets me the name

Comment: I have used it in place of  "if(counter != null)"